# A tool to acquire tasks

Tags: linux, scheduled-task

I have several machines that I want to use them in the following way: There is a central queue of tasks/jobs(that i can define) on some machine, there are other machines that when are free of tasks they should go to that machine and acquire a task to be implemented form that queue. I don't want to log into all synchronization problems and implement the protocol myself. I'm pretty sure this is something like that in open source, can you point me some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a piece of software called a "batch scheduler", which is common in HPC. Popular open source ones are Sun Grid Engine (SGE), Torque, and SLURM.